# Fragment navigation using activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity that contains a view pager with fragments in it. I also have a navigation drawer that has fragments. whenever I'm starting my app, in main activity, I'm adding the first fragment to the fragment manager, so it will shown whenever the app is starting.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     home = new FragmentHome();

    mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityToolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        home = new FragmentHome();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // changed the back stack here..
        String Tag = "start";
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_container, home, Tag).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    }

    FragmentNavigationDrawer fragmentNavigationDrawer = (FragmentNavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_contain_drawer);
    fragmentNavigationDrawer.setUpDrawer(R.id.fragment_contain_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mainToolbar);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment", home);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        home = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");
    }
}
@Override
public void changeToolBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

in the navigation drawer adapter I have a method that get the fragments and show or add them when needed. my main problem that I cant figure how to solve is that I'm trying to keep the state of first fragment(which contain a recycler view with array list of custom object), while switching to other fragments in the drawer and display their content

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position){
    // Add the fragments only once
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(navigationDrawerFragmentsTags[position]) == null)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_container,navigationDrawerFragments[position],navigationDrawerFragmentsTags[position]);
    }

    // Hiding & Showing fragments
    for(int i=0;i<navigationDrawerFragments.length;i++)
    {
        if(i == position)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.show(navigationDrawerFragments[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if the fragment is added and then hide it
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(navigationDrawerFragmentsTags[i]) != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(navigationDrawerFragments[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

however the first fragment that was added is always exists beneath the other layers and I cant hide it. i want to keep it state, but also to hide when I'm going to another fragment and I need to keep its content to display the list when the user is going back to this fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    itemList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_items);
    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.drawer_item_views, addItemsToList());
    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

I tried to use interfaces, I tried to look in google but I cant find an answer to that.

//

Answer (score 0):

to keep the state, add it to backstack

and instead of adding new fragment, just replace your fragment i.e. remove older and then add new one. i.e. fragmentTransaction.replace() instead of fragmentTransaction.add()

Comment: I used replaced instead, and that helps. but when I'm switching fragments the list in the first fragment is no longer there. the fragment that host the view pager is added to back stack but still it seems that this fragment is recreated again every time..